# Can a brake booster vacuum hose malfunction in a situation where the car is wet but work fine when the car is dry?

Tags: brakes, brake-booster

I'm posting this in follow up to [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/61592/how-long-should-disc-brakes-take-to-slow-the-car-when-wet) question.

To summarize, when conditions are wet (snow or rain) after a few minutes without braking my car will lose the ability to slow down quickly. I'd describe the feeling as if the pads just aren't gripping the rotors correctly. Almost as if there's oil on the rotor and it takes a few seconds to clean it off before regular braking is regained.

I should also mention that it doesn't matter how long the brakes have been wet for, if I take the car through the car wash I lose proper braking immediately afterwards pretty much until I'm out of the parking lot.

*I want to highlight that this situation only happens in wet conditions (warm or cold). When the roads are dry the brakes work perfectly.*

I've had the car into the dealership twice now and both times they've claimed that nothing seems to be wrong with the pads, rotors or anything on the brake itself. Today they mentioned that they'll try replacing the brake booster vacuum hose so my questions is:

**Can a brake booster vacuum hose malfunction in a situation where the car is wet but work fine when the car is dry?**

I'm asking because I'd prefer not to have my car into the dealership half a dozen times while they try different fixes. I'm not an expert but from what I know about brake boosters, it doesn't seem like something that could malfunction only while wet. To me if the hose was compromised, I would assume the issue would always be present.

Comment: Is perhaps the anti-lock system messing up?

Comment: @mike65535 Possibly, I don't now a lot about the anti-lock system. Could it be that when the car is wet the ABS thinks the wheels are locked so it doesn't apply full pressure to the brakes?

Comment: Most cars with ABS will show a light on the dash when ABS is kicking in. Does yours?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot No, there's no light on the dash when the issue is happening.