# Can performance brakes (Brembo's) be used on road trips in the rain?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

This is a follow up question to my never ending situation regarding the stock brakes on the 2018 Subaru BRZ SportTech RS (they're Brembo's from the factory):

- [How long should disc brakes take to slow the car when wet?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/61592/how-long-should-disc-brakes-take-to-slow-the-car-when-wet)
- [Can a brake booster vacuum hose malfunction in a situation where the car is wet but work fine when the car is dry?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/65185/can-a-brake-booster-vacuum-hose-malfunction-in-a-situation-where-the-car-is-wet)

**Recap:**

Essentially, my brakes don't decelerate as well on the highway when conditions are wet versus when they're dry. The two questions above provide a proper description.

**New Developments:**

Just today I talked to the dealership, and they claim that this might be an issue with all the Brembo's that come on this model. Basically, the service representative explained the problem by saying that with these Brembo's there's always a slight "hairline" amount of contact to keep them heated and better preforming. This may be causing the rotors to become "glazed" and faulty in wet conditions.

Essentially, this means that every new BRZ with this set of brakes would have the same issue. It could even imply that every performance set of brakes that apply that same about of hairline contact could fail in specific situations as well.

The dealership solution was to scuff the rotors and then just re-scuff them every time the problem returns.

**Question:**

*Are vehicles with performance brakes unable to be used on the highway in the rain, due to the poor design of the brakes?*

To me it seems highly unlikely that a car manufacturer would include Brembo's on a vehicle if they're not usable on road trips.

Comment: Given racing cars can stop in the rain - it may be a tire issue as well as or even more than the brakes... Also, don't the Subaru's do fairly well in some of the rallies... wet conditions especially in some UK stages.

Comment: @SolarMike This situation is a bit unique because it only happens after excess periods without braking (20 minutes+). I've tried to check the tires as well. Once the brakes have been "cleaned" by applying them a few times, stopping returns to normal, meaning that even though the road is still wet, if I slam on the brakes the car comes to a quick stop. Something I would expect not to happen intermittently if it was a tire issue.

Comment: So, what grade pads are you using? try a softer grade ie not so close to a "race" spec...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm sure I could swap out parts myself to fix the situation but that's slightly aside from the point. I'm more curious to see if the situation described by the dealer is possible. Meaning, is Subaru really selling a car with parts that don't function all the time.

Comment: Yah, this is a "brake pad" problem, not a "brake caliper" problem. It isn't the brake calipers which are causing you issues, it's brake pad material. Many track enthusiasts have track specific pads which they use while at the track and change them out (coming and going) if the car doubles as a street car.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That makes sense, and might be the case here. Is it really possible though for a stock car to come with pads that aren't suitable for daily use? It seems like something the manufacturer would have taken into account.

Comment: Sure, but any brake/rotors need to be warmed up before they achieve their optimum performance. Best suggestion is to slow down in the rain and be prepared for the lesser braking until they warm up.

Comment: I'm confused, does OP want racing brakes or not? Racing anything is a compromise, accepting superior performance under some circumstances in trade for poor performance in others. I think the expectation that racing equipment should function identically to street equipment is misplaced. The fact that the manufacturer labels this vehicle as "sport tech rs" should indicate it is not a normally equipped vehicle. Welcome to the world of driving a race-equipped car on the streets.

Comment: @TimNevins That's an excellent point, and you're right I am new to this world. I guess I'm just surprised Subaru would equip the car with such track oriented brakes that don't hold up in everyday situations.

Comment: This comment chain is getting a bit long, but I just wanted to chime in and say that most OEM solutions are nowhere near as aggressive or compromising as true "race" products. I might expect a small decrease in braking; but going by the description from the linked older questions, for something as critical for safety as the brakes, up to 2 seconds of no brakes seems highly unusual for stock sport models. I'd probably say this is a specific case to this model of BRZ, or it might possibly just be your car.